Brake fluid reservoir full despite spill
I just got an oil change and as part of the service they checked the fluids. Afterwards I took the car home and replaced the front brakes. When I was pushing the first cylinder back in brake fluid came out of the reservoir. It was a decent sized puddle. I checked the cap and it was loose, so I am assuming the shop did not close it properly.
After finishing the brake job I drove the car a little then checked the level in the reservoir and it is at the max line. I am sure that more fluid spilled on the ground than would fit in the space left in the reservoir.
My question is why is the reservoir still at the max level? Did it suck in a bunch of air so I need to bleed the lines? The brake pedal feels spongy, but that is normal for that car. 2013 Buick Encore.

Presumably you changed your brake pads because the old pads were worn thin; the new pads are thicker. The difference in thickness times the sum of the areas of the calipers' piston's face equals the volume of brake fluid that is now in your reservoir instead of being in the brake calipers.
Don't slap yourself on the forehead too hard . . . .
If you had started with a topped-off reservoir and worn brake pads, after installing the pads you would have had an overfilled reservoir. It's just random luck that you ended up after spillage and new pads with exactly the right level of fluid.

I don't know if it's random luck, or more so the master cylinder just purged what it didn't need. One of the reasons why you shouldn't add more fluid between brake jobs unless you are changing the brake fluid itself.
